# Derivative of x[x]

Tags: derivatives

What will be the derivative of x[x] when x is not an integer?

I was applying the product rule but I'm stuck in the part were I have to differentiate [x] wrt x.

[.] Denotes greatest integer function

Comment: What does the notation "[.]" denote?

Comment: Greatest integer function

Comment: What does the graph of $[x]$ look like, when $x$ is not an integer. Doesn't that tell you what the derivative is?

Comment: Ok I get it that's 0

Comment: @GerryMyerson thanks

Comment: Hint: on intervals of the form $(n,n+1)$ where $n$ is an integer the function $x\mapsto x\lfloor x\rfloor$ coincides with $x\mapsto nx$ (which is easy to differentiate). I would leave out the product rule.

Comment: Just to be clear, the answer to your question is not $0$.  Suppose $2<x<3$, just to pick.  Then $\lfloor x \rfloor=2$ so in that interval $f(x)=2x$.  The derivative of $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is $0$ (where it is defined).

Comment: The derivative is defined in $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must evaluate:
$$\frac{d}{dx} ([x]\cdot x) \tag{1}$$
Your idea to use the product rule is a good one. Therefore:
$$\frac{d}{dx} ([x]\cdot x)=[x]\cdot \frac{d}{dx} (x)+x\cdot \frac{d}{dx}([x]) \tag{2}$$
Note that $[x]$ is locally constant for $x\not\in \mathbb{Z}$. It follows that $\frac{d}{dx}([x])=0$ where $x\not\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Therefore, what can you deduce about the solution to $(1)$ using $(2)$?

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{d}{dx} (x[x]) = [x]\cdot \frac{d}{dx} (x) + x\cdot \frac{d}{dx} ([x])
=[x]\cdot 1 + x\cdot 0
=[x]
$$